# Migrate to Bootstrap 4 from Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 3 in my project. I see that Bootstrap 4 is a major rewrite of almost the entire Bootstrap project. But is there any necessity to migrate to bootstrap 4 from 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make your project a bit *future-proof*!

---

http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com gives an overview in code for what is different from Bootstrap 3 to 4, I suggest you visit it.

Also it seems there are several changes, regarding:

1. Browser support
2. Global changes
3. Components
4. Misc

and more, as mentioned in [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/), which you should take into account. Notice that it also confirms what you are claiming:

> Bootstrap 4 is a major rewrite of almost the entire project.

---

It's not that you **must upgrade** now or your app will live in hell, but it seems that many new cool things are happening in [bootstrap-4](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4), so the question is, do you want your app to be OK for now, or to make it a bit *future-proof*? It's up to you!